# Assign names to the vector elements of a list in R

Tags: r, character, lapply

I was wondering if we could we assign names to each vector element in the output of function `foo` below?

For the example below, giving elements of `$pubs` names: `"pubs_-1SD"`, `"pubs_+1SD"` and for the elements of `$time` names: `"time_-1SD"`, `"time_+1SD"`?

```
data <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/salary.csv')

foo <- function(data, vars) lapply(data[,vars], function(x) mean(x) + c(-1, 1)*sd(x))

foo(data, c("pubs", "time")) # EXAMPLE OF USE

# $pubs
# [1]  5.348203 33.909862 ## `"pubs_-1SD"` and `"pubs_+1SD"

# $time
# [1]  3.312931 12.848359 ## `"time_-1SD"` and `"time_+1SD"`
```

Comment: Not sure I get your expected output clearly. Could you be more explicit about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the column names in `sapply` and assign names using `setNames` :

```
foo <- function(data, vars) sapply(vars, function(x) 
  setNames(mean(data[[x]]) + c(-1, 1)*sd(data[[x]]), 
           paste0(x, '_', c('-', '+'), '1SD')), simplify = FALSE)

foo(data, c("pubs", "time"))

#$pubs
#pubs_-1SD pubs_+1SD 
# 5.348203 33.909862 

#$time
#time_-1SD time_+1SD 
# 3.312931 12.848359
```

Comment: In that case change the `paste0` line to  : `paste0(x, c('_-1SD', '_Mean', '_+1SD')))`

Comment: Got it thanks! What not using `lapply` instead of `sapply`?

Comment: Because `lapply` loses top-level names `$pubs`, `$time`, `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `Map`

```
foo <- function(data, vars) {
          
           Map(function(x, y) setNames(mean(x) + c(-1, 1)*sd(x), 
                sprintf('%s_%s1SD', rep(y, 2), c('-', '+'))), data[,vars], vars)
    }
     
    
     
foo(data, c("pubs", "time"))
#$pubs
#pubs_-1SD pubs_+1SD 
# 5.348203 33.909862 

#$time
#time_-1SD time_+1SD 
# 3.312931 12.848359
```